# ASP.NET MV6, WEB API, ENTITY 7 Controller not executing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing, entity-framework-core

The issue I am having is, when ever I try to run my controller methods from the URL bar e.g. localhost://5000/api/course/GetCourseById/1 it does not execute, the page refreshes to the startup "Welcome - Your ASP.NET 5 application has been successfully started" page.

Please see below code and screen shot.

## Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using School.Context;
using School.Services;
using School.Interfaces;
using School.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace School
{
    public class Startup
    {
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //setup configuration sources
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("config.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //add services to container
        services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<SchoolDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        services.AddMvc();

        //resolve dependency injections
        services.AddScoped<IRegistrationRepo, RegistrationRepo>();          
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
   }
}
```

## CourseController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using School.Interfaces;
using School.Models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace School.Controllers
{
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    private IRegistrationRepo _registrationRepo;

    public CourseController(IRegistrationRepo registrationRepo)
    {
        _registrationRepo = registrationRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Course> GetAllCourses()
    {
        return _registrationRepo.GetCourses();
    }

    [HttpGet("{courseId:int}", Name = "GetCourseById")]
    public IActionResult GetCourseById(int courseId)
    {
        var course = _registrationRepo.GetCourse(courseId);
        if (course == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(course);
    }

   }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the route definition you have

```
[HttpGet("{courseId:int}", Name = "GetCourseById")]
```

It does not say `GetCourseById` in the url template. So with the above route defintion, it will work for the request url  `http://yoursitename/api/Course/1`

If you wan't it to work for `yoursitename/api/course/GetCourseById/1` , You should update the route definition for this action method like.

```
[HttpGet("GetCourseById/{courseId:int}")]
public IActionResult GetCourseById(int courseId)
{
    return Content("Do something useful for " + courseId);
}
```